# Django + iis request.body problems

Tags: django, iis, encoding

Localhost used is macOS 10.13 python 3.6 django 2.0.2

windowServer2012R2 used django 2.0.2, python 3.4, iis,fastCGI

If I run localhost, this screenshot I have:

[image]

And putting data and post return 200 connect success:

[image]

But CSS is not working on the window Server.

This screenshot:

[image]

And put data and post produce:

exception the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
 in `json.loads(request.body)`

Django debug Post data

```
_content_type   
'application/json'
_content    
('{\r\n'
 '    "UserEmail": "",\r\n'
 '    "UserPassword": "",\r\n'
 '    "UserSex": 1,\r\n'
 '    "UserAge": 1,\r\n'
 '    "DeviceId": "",\r\n'
 '    "PushKey": "",\r\n'
 '    "OS": 1,\r\n'
 '    "OSVersion": ""\r\n'
 '}')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8cxO.png)

I think its an encoding problem, but I can't solve it.

localhost

```
print(request.body)
```

result

```
`b'{\n    "UserEmail": "",\n    "UserPassword": "",\n    "UserSex": 1,\n    "UserAge": 1,\n    "DeviceId": "",\n    "PushKey": "",\n    "OS": 1,\n    "OSVersion": ""\n}'`
```

windowserver

```
`b'_content_type=application%2Fjson&_content=%7B%0D%0A++++%22UserEmail%22%3A+%22%22%2C%0D%0A++++%22UserPassword%22%3A+%22%22%2C%0D%0A++++%22UserSex%22%3A+1%2C%0D%0A++++%22UserAge%22%3A+1%2C%0D%0A++++%22DeviceId%22%3A+%22%22%2C%0D%0A++++%22PushKey%22%3A+%22%22%2C%0D%0A++++%22OS%22%3A+1%2C%0D%0A++++%22OSVersion%22%3A+%22%22%0D%0A%7D'`
```

I tried `json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))`
exception this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kZwx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
import json

body_string = request.body.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
data = json.loads(body_string)
```

or just try like

```
data = json.loads(request.data.get('_content'))
```

Comment: same exception of last screenshot at post

Comment: @Adam try like `data = request.json()`

Comment: exception 'Request' object has no attribute 'json'  so i tried request.data 
`print(request.data)

<QueryDict: {'_content': ['{\r\n    "UserEmail": "",\r\n    "UserPassword": "",\r\n    "UserSex": 1,\r\n    "UserAge": 1,\r\n    "DeviceId": "",\r\n    "PushKey": "",\r\n    "OS": 1,\r\n    "OSVersion": ""\r\n}'], '_content_type': ['application/json']}>`



but  `json.loads(request.data)

exception the JSON object must be str, not 'QueryDict'`

Comment: @Adam oh! then try `data = json.loads(request.data.get('_content'))`